# In what circumstances is Meteor.user() not reactive?

Tags: meteor

I have a template helper

```
  multiple_emails: ->
    Meteor.user().emails.length > 1
```

It is not rerun when objects are added or removed from the emails array. Why is this? How should I write this helper to that it is rerun?

Comment: In the start, the user wont be signed in, and `Meteor.user()` will evaluate to `null`, which doesn't have the property `emails`. You don't get any error message indicating this?

Comment: Using fast-render, so usually not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something does not work somewhere else in your code.

I made you a small pad : http://meteorpad.com/pad/B6L3cCXAPwPSdqc5s

Template :

```
<head>
  <title>Leaderboard</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> loginButtons}}
  {{#if currentUser}}
   {{> addEmail}}
  {{/if}}
</body>

<template name="addEmail">
  <button>addEmail</button>
  nb: {{emails}}
</template>
```

Client Js :

```
Template.addEmail.events({
  'click button': function() {
    Meteor.users.update({
      _id: Meteor.userId()
    }, {
      $addToSet: {
        emails: {address: 'email' + Math.random()}
      }
    })
  }
});

Template.addEmail.helpers({
  emails: function() {
    return Meteor.user().emails.length;
  }
});
```

You'll need the accounts-base, password and ui packages.

Signup with an email and click le addemail button. As you can see, when clicking on the button, it updates the number (and quickly goes back to 1 because you cannot update it that way, but this is just to make a general point).

Comment: Moral of the story: check your console output, there's an error there which you need to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Most times when a collection does not appear to be reactive on the client side, there is an issue/mistake somewhere in the pub/sub portion.

Comment: I took a long hard look at my publish function and found the issue, I didn't know other code in the publish function is not reactive. So in my case the result from a Mongo query was used in the publish query and of course that result never changed.